# Is it good to use Django ContentType Framework, or to keep it simple with M2M Relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-contenttypes

I'm having a dilemma on choosing whether to use `ContentType` or using `ManyToManyField`.

Consider the following example:

```
class Book(Model):
    identifiers  = ManyToManyField('Identifier')
    title = CharField(max_length=10)

class Series(Model):
    identifiers  = ManyToManyField('Identifier')
    book = ForeignKey('Book')
    name = CharField(max_length=10)

class Author(Model):
    identifiers = ManyToManyField('Identifier')
    name = CharField(max_length=10)

class Identifier(Model):
    id_type = ForeignKey('IdType')
    value = CharField(max_length=10)

class IdType(Model):
    # Sample Value:
    # Book: ISBN10, ISBN13, LCCN
    # Serial: ISSN
    # Author: DAI, AIS

    name = CharField(max_length=10)
```

As you notice, `Identifier` is being used in many places, and in fact, it is so generic that many business related object requires `Identifier`, similar to [how `TagItem` from the Django examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) is being used.

---

An alternative approach is to generalized this using the Generic Relation.

```
class Book(Model):
    identifiers = GenericRelation(Identifier)
    title = CharField(max_length=10)
    authors = ManyToManyField(Author)

class Series(Model):
    identifiers = GenericRelation(Identifier)
    book = ForeignKey('Book')
    name = CharField(max_length=10)

class Author(Model):
    identifiers = GenericRelation(Identifier)
    name = CharField(max_length=10)

class Identifier(Model):

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    id_type = ForeignKey('IdType')
    value = CharField(max_length=10)

class IdType(Model):
    # Sample Value:
    # Book: ISBN10, ISBN13, LCCN, MyLibrary, YourLibrary, XYZLibrary, etc.
    # Serial: ISSN, XYZSerial, etc...
    # Author: DAI, AIS, XYZAuthor, etc...

    name = CharField(max_length=10)
```

---

I'm unsure if I'm raising the right concern regarding Generic Relation.

1. I'm worried about the data growth of the `Identifier` table, as it will grow very fast on one table, for example:

   - 100,000 books, average 4 identifiers each. (total 400,000 identifier records)
   - average 2 authors per book (total 200,000 identifier records)

   For each record in book, 4-6x data increased in identifier table. Soon, Identifier Table will be millions of records. Will the queries becoming very slow in the long run? Moreover, I believed that identifier is a field that being queried and used in the application.
2. Is this generalization correctly done? As in, Author Identifier is completely unrelated with Book Identifier and should have its own `BookIdentifier` and `AuthorIdentifier` on its own. Although they seems to have `IdType.name` and `IdType.value` pattern, but the domain are completely not related, one is author, the other is book. Should they be generalized? Why not?

What problem could there be if I were to implement under GenericRelation model?

Comment: What's the point of using generic relations here ? Besides, if your "identifiers" are actually model-specific, what's the point of over-generalizing ? Not that millions of records should be a problem for any half-decent SQL database - specially with small-size records like those - but will it make your code easier to maintain ?

Comment: I like to follow conventions because it produce a certain level of understandability. But in this case, because it make sense to call a `Book` has many to many `Identifier` via a `BookIdentifier`. Rather than calling it `Book` has many to many `BookIdentifier` via `BookBookIdentifier`. Same happens to `Author`. So, I'm thinking whether to combine such unrelated `Identifier` (book, author, and more) into one generic `Identifier` model for all kind of identifiers. Hoping it is more understandable in the code level, but mess the database layer as it mixed up the author and book under one table.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers And since many to many produced an extra join table, it is harder to understand the database layer as you will have more table to look at, I minimized that by putting it as a generic relation. But this is just another abstraction to minimize the number of tables created.

Comment: I'm afraid we're mostly  in the "opinion-based" territory here.

Comment: hmm... alright then... I'll close this question, since it doesn't seems useful.